# How I can declare a array of n+1 elements in bash scripting?

Tags: arrays, bash

Here is the code. I want to declare an array of n+1 elements and those values should be zero. In below code, I have a simple array. Can anyone tell me how I can declare an array of n+1 elements?

```
declare -a arr
for (( j=0;j<=n;j++ ))
do
  arr+=(0)
done
```

Comment: Replace `n` with `n+1`?

Comment: Isn't `|{0,...,n}|=n+1`?

Comment: This: `n=10; read -ra array < <(printf -v e %\*s $((n + 1)) ''; printf %s "${e// /0 }")`

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, James and Gris, I tried this and this worked for me.
declare -a arr[n+1]
for (( j=0;j<=n;j++ ))
do
    arr+=(0)
done

#echo "${arr[@]}"

Comment: Hi All, thanks for helping me out. Please review one more problem, I'm facing. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233725/error-getting-in-the-second-if-statement-in-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit overkill, but with a helper function that prints X copies of a given value...

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rep() {
    local count="$1" val="$2" n
    for (( n = 0; n < count; n++ )); do
        printf "%q\n" "$val"
    done
}

n=10
declare -a arr="( $(rep $(( n + 1 )) 0) )"
declare -p arr # arr has 11 elements, all 0
```

Comment: Hi James, It's good to hear from you.  Please review one more problem, I'm facing. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233725/error-getting-in-the-second-if-statement-in-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

> how I can declare an array of n+1 elements?

To declare an array of any elements, also `n+1` elements, just assign to the array like `arr=( <n+1 things> )`.

You could print `n+1` zeros and assign them to an array:

```
arr=($(printf "0%.s " $(seq $((n + 1)))))
```

Comment: `seq` is not very standard and this kind of array assignment from a command output will get shellcheck inspection warning [SC2207 **Prefer mapfile or read -a to split command output \(or quote to avoid splitting\).**](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without a loop if you can follow this trick:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# set n
n=5

# read the array from space delimited fields
# generated by the printf commands
# in the sub-shell below
read -r -a array < <(
  # print format n+1 spaces into variable str
  printf -v str '%*s' $((n + 1)) ''

  # Replace each space in str by 0 and space
  # line: 0 0 0 0 0 ..
  printf %s "${str// /0 }"
)

# Debug dump array declaration
declare -p array
```

Debug output:

```sh
declare -a array=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0")
```

The above script can fit into a one-line declaration for the array:

```sh
read -ra array < <(printf -v e %\*s $((n+1)) '';printf %s "${e// /0 }")
```

Comment: Hi Lea (sorry If I pronounced your name wrong), As I'm a new learner in bash scripting, I'm thankful for having your time. I just got to know new things. Well, I've post the whole problem that I've been working on. Please go through that one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233725/error-getting-in-the-second-if-statement-in-bash-script