# Error getting in the second if statement in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

```
n=20
x=3
count=0
flag=0
i=1
declare -a arr[n+1]
for (( j=0;j<=n;j++ ))
do
  arr+=(0)
done

#echo "${arr[@]}"

while [[ $count -ne $n ]]
do
if [[ $i -le $n ]]
then 
    if [[ ${arr[$i]} -eq '0' ]]
    then
            echo "Value is ${arr[$i]}"
            #${arr[$(i-1)]}= (( ${arr[$i-1]++} ))
            ${arr[$i]}+=${arr[$i]}
            echo " "
            #echo -n "${arr[$i]}"
            echo -n " $i"
            count=$(( count+1 ))
            i=$(( i+1+x ))
    else
        i=$(( i+1 ))
    fi
else
    i=$(( i-n ))
    flag=$(( flag+1 ))
fi
done

 echo " "
 echo "No of round : $flag"
```

This is the whole code, I've tried to print numbers that follows this: n=20 is the number of elements and  x=3 is the number that we have to avoid. For example,
20
3
1,5,9,13,17,2,6,10,14,18,3,7,11,15,19,4,8,12,16,20,
3
But, the problem is that my second if condition is not fulfilling, if ignores the condition. Above example is for the C++, but in bash script, 2nd if statement isn't working. This can be because syntax is wrong. So can you please help me to find the mistakes.
Output of the above code:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcpVz.png)

Comment: I haven't looked at your logic, but syntactically, line 32 is wrong.  Maybe you meant to write `arr[$i]+=${arr[$i]}`, but that is not doing arithmetic, but appending strings. Maybe that's what you intend.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There's error in line 32 but if I correct that one even then, how I'm being end up inside the if statement. It should follows the condition. The value (I initialized the value of all the elements 0 at the starting) of arr indices must satisfy the condition. For example, if it sees 1==0, then why it's going inside the statement, means something is wrong in if syntax. That's what I've trying to find.

Comment: When would it ever see `1`?  When you use `+=`, '0' + '0' becomes the string `00`.  But `-eq` is integer comparison, not string comparison, and `[[ 00 -eq 0 ]]` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ${arr[$i]}+=${arr[$i]}
```

This is incorrect. $ should not be used when you assign the value.
If you want to double the value, replace this string with the following:

```
        arr[$i]=$(( ${arr[$i]} + ${arr[$i]} ))
```

Or what you want to do there?